# Telerik RadWindow opens only first time

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, radwindow

This is my code please have a look:

```
<telerik:RadWindow  ID="modalPopup" runat="server" Width="360px" Height="360px">
               <ContentTemplate>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">
                     <h3>Data</h3>                       
                     <telerik:RadGrid ID="RGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" OnNeedDataSource="RGrid_NeedDataSource">
                     <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="true"></MasterTableView>
                     </telerik:RadGrid>    
                    </p>
               </ContentTemplate>
          </telerik:RadWindow>
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="rdbScripts">
          <script type="text/javascript">    
              function showDialogInitially() {
                  //alert("786");

                  var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
                 wnd.show();

               //   Sys.Application.remove_load(showDialogInitially);
              }     
          </script>
     </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

It is working only first time but as I close the window and press button again It does not open anymore.

Comment: I suggest you to post also the button code.

Comment: Here is the code for button<telerik:RadButton ID="btnPreview" Text="Preview"  runat="server" OnClientClicked="showDialogInitially()"   />

Comment: as I click preview button it worked fine but as I close window then It does not work next time

Answer (score 0):

Fix the button so it:

- does not postback
- properly executes the function without throwing an error

Here is how:

```
 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnPreview" Text="Preview" runat="server" OnClientClicked="showDialogInitially" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

And here are more explanations on that: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/12-08-10/migrating-onclientclick-handlers-from-asp-button-to-telerik-s-asp-net-ajax-button.aspx.

Comment: Hello
It didnt help I have placed another button in code 
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnTestCon" Text="Test Connection" 
            runat="server" onclick="btnTestCon_Click"/>
and in code behind I have done nothing but as I click this button 
radwindow gets opens and It also didnt work on preview button :(

Comment: Well then, post your entire code so we can see what's wrong. At first look I saw incorrect client-side  handler and I explained that.
Also, take a look here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx and ensure you don't use the VisibleOnPageLoad property.